# Possible to Peek in a Multi-Processing Queue

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

Can a subscriber pull from multiprocessing Queue but not remove that element in the queue?

My usecase is: I have a 'Stock Market Feed' Queue that contains stock order objects. I have 3 `TradingStrategy` (TS) worker threads. Each needs to receive **every** message in the feed. So if the first TS thread pulls a message from the queue the next 2 threads wont receive that message because its been removed from the queue.

Is there a way to peek at the queue? And once all threads have read the message I can pull that message from the queue?

Comment: just a suggestion you can use `deque` in `collections` and add dictionaries containing message and  count every one read message from `deque` and count not equal 0 `appendleft` dict to `deque` after updating `count=count-1`

Comment: "multiprocessing Queue" doesn't make a lot sense when you're talking about threads.  What is that?  A python `queue` object created by a fourth thread?

Comment: Can you have a queue for each worker? When a message is generated it goes into every workers queue and they deal with it when they get to it.